# How to check if a string is null in python

Tags: python, string, null

I have a value cookie that is returned from a POST call using Python.
I need to check whether the `cookie` value is empty or null.
Thus I need a function or expression for the if condition.
How can I do this in Python?
For example:

```
if cookie == NULL

if cookie == None
```

P.S. `cookie` is the variable in which the value is stored.

Comment: What web framework are you using?

Comment: You need to describe what function you use for getting your cookie value: this will tell us what to test for (`None` value? empty string only?).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try this:

```
if cookie and not cookie.isspace():
    # the string is non-empty
else:
    # the string is empty
```

The above takes in consideration the cases where the string is `None` or a sequence of white spaces.

Comment: `cookie.isspace()` is more efficient than using `strip`

Answer (score 5):

In python, `bool(sequence)` is `False` if the sequence is empty.  Since strings are sequences, this will work:

```
cookie = ''
if cookie:
    print "Don't see this"
else:
    print "You'll see this"
```

Comment: what if you have have - cookie = "null" then bool(cookie) return True.

Comment: what's the difference in functionality between `if cookie` and `if cookie == ""`?

Comment: Although the answer is valid for the grand majority of cases, the OP wanted to check if the string was `None` or empty (containing whitespace), e.g. `'   '` or `'\n\t'`.